# Send email in meteor with Amazon ses

Tags: email, meteor, amazon-ses

I have two details for sending the email with amazon ses:

The first is about sending using non-reply for now I can only send using my mail which I set up with the amazon account. Reading say that I should add some files that they give me with a key and place them on the server of my web and thus be able to send with the name of the domain but amazon never got those files on my server as noreply@domain-name.com , Put in the public folder meteor files but amazon never can validate them, is there any method to perform this process?

The second is the configuration if I assign the settings.json variables with the name and key for example

```js
//Settings.json
 {
   "AWSScretUserSes": "xxxxxxxx"
   "AWSScretPassSes": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
 }
 
//index.js in the folder server
Meteor.startup (() => {
Process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp: // AWSScretUserSes: AWSScretPassSes@email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com: 465 /';
});
 Console.log (AWSScretUserSes);
```

If I put it this way I do not send mail, so I see process.env.MAIL_URL does not read the variables that I put as the name and password of the amazon ses and in console.log I do I can see that the AWSScretUserSes and AWSScretPassSes are working. I do not know if there is anything that prevents the operation or another method to safely send passwords and Amazon keys.

Comment: Process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://'+AWSScretUserSes+':'+AWSScretPassSes+'@email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:465/';

Comment: @iiro Thank you for responding, you know how to do it from noreply@xxxx.com

Comment: @Marcelrama just add a domain in domain list